# List all symbols loaded at runtime

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

Windows has a nifty tool - [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) - which lists all symbols used in an executable and the dynamic libraries from which they are loaded. This is very useful to know missing symbols & DLLs.

Is there a similar utility for *nix/Solaris. Though we can find this out with combination of  ldd and nm, a single tool will be handy.

Comment: Why not make a script that uses `nm`/`ldd` to output the information you want, which you can then publish? Remember that almost all great open-source software of today happened because a developer had "an itch to scratch". :)

Comment: @Joachim: Can't agree enough; whatever happened to the use of simple UN*X pipes and small shell aliases or scripts ...

Answer (score 0):

Attach to pid with dbx and use [funcs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1380/blazk.html#scrolltoc) command to list the loaded symbols.

```
$ dbx "-c funcs; quit "  /usr/bin/bash 4837

Reading bash
Reading ld.so.1
Reading libcurses.so.1
Reading libsocket.so.1
Reading libnsl.so.1
Reading libdl.so.1
Reading libc.so.1
Attached to process 4837
stopped in _waitid at 0xfee0af95
0xfee0af95: _waitid+0x0015:     jae      _waitid+0x21   [ 0xfee0afa1, .+0xc ]
`bash`_start
`bash`_mcount
`bash`__fsr
`bash`main
`bash`exit_shell
`bash`sh_exit
...
`libnsl.so.1`nis_sperror
`libnsl.so.1`nis_lerror
`libnsl.so.1`__nis_group_cache_stats
...
`libc.so.1`mmap64
`libc.so.1`_mmap64
`libc.so.1`_init
`libc.so.1`_fini
detaching from process 4837
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This can also be done with gdb (for those who do not use dbx) - 'info types' command. I am actually looking for a tool that will tell which so's and symbols missing. I guess gdb/dbx will only work if the program can load successfully.